# Do any other characters have Combined Attacks?

Tags: persona-4-golden

I generally have Chie and Yukiko in my party and on occasion they use a Combined Attack called Twin Dragons.

I am wondering if there are any other characters who have this kind of combined attack?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, each character besides the MC has a team-up attack.  Yosuke and Teddie have one, as well as Kanji and Naoto.